Cribbage pegging
We were playing 4 handed cribbage.  During the pegging we reached 28 and 3 players said Go.  The 4th player was left with 3 aces still in his hand.  Can he play an ace at a time and take points?  Play the first ace for 29 and take a go for 1 pt, play the 2nd ace for a pair and take 2 points, then the 3rd ace for 31 and take 8 points?  He laid down all 3 aces at once and took 8 points. I would like to know the correct rules.  Thank you.

29 (no score), 30 for 2 (pair), 31 for 8 (trips plus hitting 31) for a total of ten points.

He must play the aces one at time.
There isn't any pegging move where multiple cards are laid, and strictly he should announce the running total and the points for each card.

(Ace) 29
(Ace) 30 for 2
(Ace) 31 for 6
plus 2
total 10 points

Perhaps he thought it would be pedantic (knowing that nobody else can play), but his shortcut managed to get the wrong score.
In the "take" too, players should count out their points for the benefit of other players, not just show their hand and announce its score without enumerating it. And in the conventional sequence! It's all part of the game's etiquette.

Aside from that, this scores a total of 10 points, so he miscounted. Or more likely, hadn't considered that the pair gets to score separately before the three-of-a-kind.

@KarlKnechtel thanks, I had the 10 points but added more detail to clarify that.
